# Python | Plotting histogram with boundaries and frequencies

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have calculated interval boundaries

```
import numpy as np

boundaries = np.array([-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
```

and normalized frequencies

```
normalized_frequencies = np.array([0.10, 0.40, 0.40, 0.10])
```

> **My question**: How can I plot a histogram with the bar boundaries like `boundaries` and the y-values as `normalized_frequencies`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bar chart instead of a histogram I think. The point here is to just use the first four boundary values and then put the width equal to the spacing between the boundaries. In this case, the width is 0.5. The black `edgecolor` is to differentiate the bars.

```
import numpy as np

boundaries = np.array([-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
normalized_frequencies = np.array([0.10, 0.40, 0.40, 0.10])
width = boundaries[1] - boundaries[0]

plt.bar(boundaries[0:-1], normalized_frequencies, width=width, 
        align='edge', edgecolor='k')
```

[image]

**Second alternative is to find the center points of each interval**

```
centers = (boundaries[1:] + boundaries[:-1]) / 2
width = centers[1] - centers[0]

plt.bar(centers, normalized_frequencies, width=width, 
        align='edge', edgecolor='k')
```

Comment: +1 For the nice answer! I also changed boundaries[0:4] to boundaries[0:-1] in order to achive better invariance.

Comment: @MrYouMath: Check my alternative. It is more general. I added your suggestion

Comment: Hmm ... To be quite honest I would rather use the first way as it is easier to read. BTW how did you get the LaTeX like font?

Comment: @MrYouMath: Oh, I have turned on Tex. Use `from matplotlib import rc` and then `rc('text', usetex=True)`